# ASP.NET web api login with facebook stopped working

Tags: asp.net, facebook, oauth

I am developing an ASP.net web app which uses Facebook authentication and up until August or September the Facebook login feature was working correctly.

I took a break from developing the app for a month or so, and recently resumed development. I tried it again recently to login to the app with Facebook, and I get this error message:

> "URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs."

I haven't changed any code from my app since September or August, so something must have changed in the way Facebook processes its logins.

I have made changes to the Facebook app settings to try and fix this but nothing works.

My current settings look like this:

```
Client OAuth Login: Yes

Web OAuth Login: Yes

All the other settings under the Facebook Login product are set to No.
```

My current redirect URIs look like this:

```
https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/api/ExternalLogin/Facebook
https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/api/ExternalLogin/FacebookCallback
https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/api/signin-facebook
https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/api/ExternalLogin/Facebook/signin-facebook
```

Originally I only had the `"/FacebookCallback"` URI. I only added the others following suggestions from other questions here on Stack-overflow, but I am still getting the same error message.

Can anyone help me figure out what am I missing?

Comment: Go check what the `redirect_uri` parameter actually contains, when the login dialog URL is shown in the browser address bar and you get to see this error message.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure:

- Your *App IDs* and *Secret Keys* are correct. The *App IDs* and *Secret Keys* are all different for each app. These often cause the problem.
- Your App domain set to:

  ```
   myapp.azurewebsites.net
  ```

  [image]
- Your site URL set to:

  ```
  http://myapp.azurewebsites.net/
  ```

  [image]
- You have set URI properly like:

  ```
  http://myapp.azurewebsites.net/facebook/login/callback/
  ```

  [image]

  ### Update:
- Make sure you have placed `/` at the end of your all URIs.

  ```
  https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/api/ExternalLogin/Facebook/
  https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/api/ExternalLogin/FacebookCallback/
  https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/api/signin-facebook/
  https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/api/ExternalLogin/Facebook/signin-facebook/
  ```

### OR

```
 localhost:44396/api/ExternalLogin/FacebookCallback/
```

Comment: The AppID and the secret are correct. I had not set the App Domain, I did it now. Based on your suggestion, I set the redirect URI to http://myapp.azurewebsites.net/api/ExternalLogin/FacebookCallback, which is the actual endpoint I programmed in the app. I keep getting the same message.

Comment: Note that http://myapp.azurewebsites.net/ is an example domain, not the actual one. I substitute the real one with "myapp" for purposes of the question.

Comment: try replacing from ` myapp.azurewebsites.net` to `localhost` and see it.

Comment: I tried using using localhost as the app domain, with  https://localhost:44396/api/ExternalLogin/FacebookCallback as the Redirect URI (/api/ExternalLogin/FacebookCallback is the callback endpoint I have programmed in the app). The 44396 is the port given by Visual Studio when running the app locally on the dev machine. The result was the same, I still the same error from Facebook.

Comment: try `http://localhost/_oauth/facebook` URI instead of `localhost:44396/api/ExternalLogin/FacebookCallback` and see ??

Comment: and make sure `/` at the end of URIs and see ?

Comment: I tried with localhost:44396/api/ExternalLogin/FacebookCallback/ as the Redirect URI. Still, the problem persists.

Comment: Trying with https://localhost:44396/_oauth/facebook/ does not work, either. Is there a reason why you think this is a correct redirect URI? I mean, I don't have any API endpoints configured to respond to the /_oauth/facebook route. Maybe I'm missing something?